# Detecting Sound on a Band

Tags: microsoft-band

I have an idea that would require detecting sound near the Band. Is it possible to put the Band in listening mode from an app on the Band? If not is there another sensor like the barometer that is sensitive enough to do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Band audio sensor is not accessible by 3rd party apps.

Comment: Bummer, I have a really cool idea that sound would make easy. I'll see if I can use the other sensors.